# How to define typescipt types for functions where second parameter type depends on first parameter value

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have a piece of code implemented that reads multiple files and transforms the data into another form.

Here is an example in [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgYgSwDYRuCBnKBeKByUSARjygB99CIAmPAKDqtkRQGEB7AO2Am52eSp0RcgJRpI1Bk3iCJEEbgDedKGqicAhgFsIALigZgAJwScA5qvUA3TUiIGjpi3QC+09GKGT+K9Rp19QxMzS39bJGpHEJd3Rk9ZFCIYY01ODAAzdmNtXys1CKJgaOdzABp8qAjqYuDStw9IL2oUtMzs3OVKwqKS0O67ahq+2MboGABBJCQWCAARTWBNPP8CYTwDRO8FSrXJDa95KTiZAAVjdgArCABjYAWllfU9hTwAfk3Z5NT0rJyK1ZUWgfZqtX4dBp0G5cIxQDKCB7LXAAbUqfn86nh4nQBheJABGLU0O4vFq6MJ-i0ulxGSpEDwBIpNjsDnwhXoTLi-lcjKg5IxWO2uKBDMq-mJPG4Bn5TLpNLptF5TOquOqHIpXPU7gAugxibCkOxNAATWaI-gACgAlDgAHx8yr64BQMAXa53RGbc5XW73RZIvmatR-KAWp1QY3+qDsDJwhH+m0y9ThwXyfiRpYAOlT6AYTPDxkwAFckH7HrgwJpjBgIGb-Rac5AyhH-ZmJaSrXmKa6fR7-cjGxBtfxCxgS2XNJUg1BC8Ai8ZOC63b7EQw4uGTG0-tovubcA340tPnJhFbj0kwe0cnaHf5Z-PF0mCizaoLEZm6UrmZFX4fNJnCinSENx+K8d0Eag91DN9-XPbZqDPUFQO3G9+XvBdbwpHpfxQd9PzFb8hhw+ZW2qID1xhZ1K2rWs-0tQc4PkDBm0FDgSSlLw2MlYAbWwe1+QwAB3BBgBuAALaCT0gRMCKJTQa0odZpVkjF0MXTdwRyXd61YrhuM7TkVJueToBeWhlKZO8IDnDCNLA2ZIJ0wQuI7FT3CZY0IAyTRxwMFSrJsx93K1NwgA)

I have some type definitions as follows

```
type TFileTypes = 'type1' | 'type2'

type TFileContentType = TFileType1 | TFileType2

type TFileType1 = {
    name: string
    val1: string
}

type TFileType2 = {
    name: string
    val2: string
}

type TFile1Transform = {
    val1t: string,
    val2t: string
}

type TFile2Transform = {
    val11t: string
    val22t: string
}

type TProjectData = {
    'type1'?: TFile1Transform,
    'type2'?: TFile2Transform
}
```

I have some function that uses these types as follows

```
const fileData = [
    {
        fileType: 'type1',
        content: {
            name: 'fname',
            val1: 'val1'
        }

    },
    {
        fileType: 'type2',
        content: {
            name: 'fname2',
            val2: 'val2'
        }

    }
]

const loadFileData = () => {
    const projectData: TProjectData = {}

    for (const data of fileData) {
        const fileType = data.fileType

        const resultData = parseFileData(fileType, data.content)

        projectData[fileType] = resultData
    }

    return projectData

}

const transformFile1Data = (fileData: TFileType1): TFile1Transform => {
    return {
        val1t: fileData.name,
        val2t: fileData.val1
    }
}

const transformFile2Data = (fileData: TFileType2): TFile2Transform => {
    return {
        val11t: fileData.name,
        val22t: fileData.val2
    }
}

const parseFileData = (fileType: TFileTypes, fileData: TFileContentType) => {
    switch(fileType) {
        case 'type1': {
            return transformFile1Data(fileData)
        }
        case 'type2': {
            return transformFile2Data(fileData)
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure on how to use the type system in parseFileData as it shows error at `transformFile1Data(fileData)` and `transformFile2Data(fileData)` because parseFileData accepts `TFileDataType` and it depends on the fileType.

Much appreciated if I could get help on more insights about how to properly implement this using typescript.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to pass both `fileType` and `fileData` to `parseFileData`? It seems that `fileType` is equal to `fileData.fileType`.

By switching on `fileData.fileType` directly, the compiler can see `fileData` is `TFileType1` if `fileData.fileType` is `'type1'`.

```
const parseFileData = (fileData: TFileDataType) => {
    switch(fileData.fileType) {
        case 'type1': {
            return transformFile1Data(fileData)
        }
        case 'type2': {
            return transformFile2Data(fileData)
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you'd need to give `fileData` a type explicitly to test this.

```
const fileData: TFileDataType[] = ...
```

Comment: I just wrote the example like so, wondering solution for type that's not in the object, should I add the type within object ?

Comment: I've updated the example a bit